# wpf display of textblock based on xml data

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm developing a kind of Store or something, where I read an RSS Feed and display its content in a ListBox. The RSS Feed contains additional data (for example "download" or "customCategory") that I use (or want to use) to sort the results of the ListBox. The ListBox looks like this:

```
<ListBox  Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ItemsListParent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,25,0,0">
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rssData}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <StackPanel Name="itemElement" Orientation="Horizontal" Loaded="itemElement_Loaded">
                        <StackPanel.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.15" />
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.85" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </StackPanel.Background>

                        <!--<Image Width="15" Margin="2" Source="{Binding XPath=url, Path=InnerText}"/>-->
                        <!--<TextBlock Margin="2" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Normal">
                            <Hyperlink Name="lnkGoToArticle" Tag="{Binding XPath=link, Path=InnerText}" Click="lnkGoToArticle_Click">
                                >>
                            </Hyperlink>
                            <Button Name="lnkDownload" Tag="{Binding XPath=download, Path=InnerText}" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="lnkDownload_Click">
                                <Image Source="Images/download31.png" Name="DownloadIcon" Width="30" Height="30" />
                            </Button>
                        </TextBlock>-->
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ListBox>
```

the code in

```
<!-- -->
```

is what I rewrote to C#, as I thought I can figure out how to sort the XML. The point is, that I've created

```
void UpdateListBox()
    {
        ItemsList.Items.Clear();

        selected = (string)CategoriesList.SelectedItem;
        //if (selected==xmldp

        /*System.Xml.XmlDocument data = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        data.Load(@"http://www.andystore.bluefile.cz/?feed=rss2");
        xmldp.Document = data;
        xmldp.XPath = "//item";*/


        Thickness mrg = new Thickness();
        mrg.Left = 2;
        mrg.Right = 2;
        mrg.Top = 2;
        mrg.Bottom = 2;
        TextBlock itemTitle=new TextBlock();
        itemTitle.Margin=mrg;
        itemTitle.FontSize=16;
        itemTitle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        itemTitle.Text = "{Binding XPath=title}";
        itemTitle.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        itemTitle.Name="itemTitle";
        Binding itemTitleBinding=new Binding();
        itemTitleBinding.XPath="title";
        itemTitle.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty,itemTitleBinding);

        itemElement.Children.Add(itemTitle);
        itemElement.RegisterName(itemTitle.Name, itemTitle);

        Label gta = new Label();
        Hyperlink goToArticle = new Hyperlink();
        goToArticle.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(lnkGoToArticle_Click);
        goToArticle.Inlines.Add(@">>");
        Binding goToArticleBinding = new Binding();
        goToArticleBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("InnerText");
        goToArticleBinding.XPath = "link";
        goToArticle.SetBinding(Hyperlink.TagProperty, goToArticleBinding);
        gta.Content = goToArticle;

        itemElement.Children.Add(gta);
        itemElement.RegisterName(goToArticle.Name, goToArticle);

        Button downloadButton = new Button();
        downloadButton.Name = "lnkDownload";
        downloadButton.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        downloadButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(lnkDownload_Click);
        Binding downloadButtonBinding = new Binding();
        downloadButtonBinding.XPath = "download";
        downloadButtonBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("InnerText");
        downloadButton.SetBinding(Button.TagProperty, downloadButtonBinding);
        Style downloadButtonStyle = this.FindResource("NoChromeButton") as Style;
        downloadButton.Style = downloadButtonStyle;
        BitmapImage dbiBitmap = new BitmapImage();
        dbiBitmap.BeginInit();
        dbiBitmap.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AndyLaunchWPF;component/Images/download31.png");
        dbiBitmap.EndInit();
        Image dbi = new Image();
        dbi.Width = 30;
        dbi.Height = 30;
        dbi.Name = "downloadIcon";
        dbi.Source = dbiBitmap;
        downloadButton.Content = dbi;

        itemElement.Children.Add(downloadButton);
        itemElement.RegisterName(downloadButton.Name, downloadButton);

        //itemElement.Children.Add(dbi);
        //itemElement.RegisterName(dbi.Name, dbi);
    }
```

but it completes the whole listbox (as before in wpf code) **without repeating the calling!!** I wanted to add somekind of condition for sorting such as if(xmldp.IDontKnowTheExactName==selectedCategory){display the textblock} else {do not display it and go to next item in XML} but i really dont know how to do it. Please be patient with me, as i am new to WPF and this is also my first question. In the case that you didn't really got what I'm trying to achieve, here is a simple list:

1) I want to load the XML and display all it's items in ItemsList

2) I want to select an item in the ListBox called categoriesList and based on the selection update ItemsList to display only items that have their customCategory==selected (selected is a string that will be updated depending on the categoriesList selection)

Problem is, I dont know where to put the condition, nor how it should look like and if it's even possible.

Hope you understood and you are able to help me.

Thanks for any answer ;) Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK forget constructing the view via code, that's not how WPF is supposed to work. Go back to your original xaml template.

Now the problem you have is that you want to sort and filter the items in the `ItemsControl`. To do this you need to bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` to a `CollectionView` based on the rssFeed, instead of binding to the rssFeed itself.

`CollectionView` allows you to easily sort and filter collections.

By the way, you appear to have a redundant `ListBox` in your XAML. It's not doing anything since you are declaring an `ItemsControl` inside it. `ListBox` already derives from `ItemsControl`.
If you want a scrollbar then just use the `ListBox`.

Comment: Yes can construct via code if you really want to, but it defeats the object of using WPF which was designed to be easily expressed in XAML and bound to the underlying data. It keeps the presentation separate from the data, so you could apply a completely different GUI to the same data if you wanted to. Have a read up on MVVM which keeps this divide very nicely.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely try! :)